# softmax cross entropy return value

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, loss, cross-entropy

What does it mean if this is the return value for `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy_loss`?

```
<tf.Tensor 'softmax_cross_entropy_loss/value:0' shape=() dtype=float32>
```

Does the fact that is states `value:0` mean and `shape=()` mean that nothing was computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has been computed because you are displaying the tensors in the graph before any data has been passed through them. Let's say

```
sce = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy_loss(input)
```

Then to actually get the loss value you have to feed data into it using

```
sess = tf.Session()
...
loss = sess.run(sce, feed_dict)
```

where feed_dict is the dictionary for your data. Loss will now return the actual numerical loss value.

`value` is just an indicator for the group of computations that the value belongs to. For example: `tf.reduce_mean` returns `tf.Tensor 'Mean_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32` because it is a mean calculation. The 0 does not mean its current value is 0, it is just used for indexing.

Additionally, your tensor shape is `()` because the single loss value doesn't have a batch size, x or y directions, or channels (assuming you are working with 4D tensors) so that is also ok.